# Umbraco 7.x vs Drupal 8.x

Tags: umbraco7, drupal-8

Currently, Im in the evaluation process between MVC CMS , I like the clean way in coding of the UMBRACO 7.0.x , with the many W3C standard which implemented there.

Recently , I found that Drupal has new release 8.0 , which has new architecture supporting MVC.

As I'm totally new to Drupal world , I would appreciate any feedback about Drupal 8.x Release From different views such as :

1. The learning curve and first setup and configuration..
2. agility & Customization
3. extensibility with plugins
4. performance & scalability
5. security
6. Community support

Any extra view points would be also appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not guru of Umbraco. But I can say a lot about Drupal 8.x which I use for the last 8 years now.

First of all here is an [overview of **the new 8.x capabilities**](https://www.drupal.org/8) which are really amazing and move Drupal to the new age.

On individual topics now here are some helpful links.

- **The learning curve**. It may be longer than usual but it deserves the
  time. See
  https://www.acquia.com/blog/conquering-the-drupal-learning-curve/25/06/2015/3285296
- **First setup and configuration**. Easy enough for a developer. Give it a try here: https://simplytest.me/project/drupal/8.2.3.
- **Agility & Customization**: By far the best fieldable and fully customized framework. You can create fields for displays, add user permissions, show results from the db and many more and all these through a UI.
- **Extensibility with plugins**: https://www.drupal.org/8/platform (3rd party libraries), https://www.drupal.org/8/standards, https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module and an issue queue for each contrib module (eg https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/pathauto?status=All).
- **Performance & scalability**: http://buytaert.net/making-drupal-8-fly
- **Security**: https://www.drupal.org/security and https://www.drupal.org/security-team. By far the most secure open source framework.
- **Community support**. https://www.drupal.org/community (By far the most promising and helpful software community on the web.)

Don't forget to check the **licenses** (not only for core but also for plugins), the **OS** supported and some additional resources such as:

- [umbraco vs. Drupal comparison](http://vschart.com/compare/umbraco/vs/drupal)
- [Comparison of the usage of Drupal vs. Umbraco for websites](https://w3techs.com/technologies/comparison/cm-drupal,cm-umbraco)

Comment: I'm sure that Drupal can't do something like Umbraco Cloud.

Comment: Umbraco cloud is just "Umbraco as a service" nothing special. There are similar products for Drupal too like the Acquia Site Factory (https://www.acquia.com/products-services/acquia-cloud-site-factory).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a guru of Drupal.
But I can say about Umbraco -

1. **The best community** - [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org/)
2. **Latest technologies** - Angular, MVC.
3. A lot of **free plugins** = http://our.umbraco.org/projects
4. Documentation - http://our.umbraco.org/documentation
5. 24 days course - http://24days.in/umbraco/2013/
6. **Umbraco Cloud** - new way of developing web-sites with Umbraco - https://umbraco.com/cloud
7. **Fully customizable**.
8. Free learn Umbraco course - https://github.com/kgiszewski/LearnUmbraco7